# ASP.NET Identity External Providers Web API without cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have seen several ways to set up external provider support for authentication in ASP.NET Web API using Identity, however all of them rely on a cookie, that is set after the user is successfully authorized by the external provider (callled "AspNet.External"), which has to be then forwarded to the token endpoint on the Web API itself.

Is there any way to circumvent this and use external authentication with ASP.NET Web API without the need to use cookies? The reason for this concern is that I would like to integrate this authentication in my mobile app, but the user can disable cookies any time, rendering my app unusable.

Comment: In regular asp.net project, you can use cookieless session using 'url' , i.e. the unique identifier to identify a session is tagged to URL as querystring. I  hope if you can get such example in web api, that will solve your purpose.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking here.  Every request has to identify itself somehow, and that is usually with a cookie because this is the most secure way to do it.  You can use a querystring parameter, but that is highly insecure because querystrings are recorded in routing and proxy logs, as well as server logs.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the request need a way to be identified, but I am not sure if a cookie is the best way to do it, because with disabled cookies the authentication will just not work. Or will the cookies be temporarily stored in the WebView even if they are actually disabled? My point is just to make sure the authentication will work on all devices.

Comment: I agree with MZetko that there isn't any information about this in the internet. I was able to use refresh tokens together with external logins, and without using cookies, using as a starting point this post from Taiseer Joudeh: http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/ but my solution was pretty ugly because I had to do a lot of modifications, so I look forward for a response to this question too. (P.D.: the client of my Web API is an angular app, not a mobile one).

Comment: @AugustoBarreto Thanks for referencing my post, but in all cases the authentication will take place in user mobile browser and the consent will be in the browser not your mobile application, it is highly unlikely that user will turn off cookies in the mobile browser.
I guess there is no workout for this.
Can you share with me how you enabled refresh token with social logins? I guess the implementation was complicated, right?

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh Looking at my code again, I am using the External cookie between the calls to Account.ExternalLogin and Account.ExternalLoginCallback. In the ExternalLoginCallback, I call AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie); to remove the cookie and then return the refresh token and the access token. Sorry for the confusion. My bad :/.

Comment: Can you not use UseCookieless with forms auth anymore. I don't know how long the Uri can be but some stuff can be done that way.

Answer (score 7):

What about using OAuth2?

1. Build a oauth2 server with https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/ ,
2. Set your server web api app as resource server, and enable oauth bearer authentication, which use Authentication header , not cookie.
3. After get access_token from oauth2 server, set the Authentication header for your client request.

you can check out the code here:

https://github.com/beginor/owin-samples

Comment: I was thinking an easier and simpler solution should be available. This would mean an almost clean from the ground implementation...